How to prevent python run program at import?
I want my python program can apply changes real time, like a php. So I write run.py to achieve this purpose.
Everybody say never use exec, then I use importlib.reload, but there is a problem, print("main1") will run two times.
If I put it into if __name__ == '__main__':, then it never run.
How to prevent the duplicate running?
original main.py
import time

def fun():
    print("main2")

while True:
    print("main1")
    fun()
    time.sleep(1)


run.py
import time
import main
import importlib

while True:
    try:
        # exec(open("main.py", encoding='utf-8').read())
        # fun()
        importlib.reload(main)
        main.fun()
    except:
        print("error")
    time.sleep(1)

main.py
def fun():
    print("main2")
    

print("main1")


What kind of program are you writing? How to reload the application depends heavily on what the application does.

e.g. if you are writing a cli tool, running the program every time the application source code changes does not make much sense.

Python isn't PHP and trying to emulate the workings of PHP isn't a valuable use of your time. You should check how hotloading/graceful reloading can be done in Python for your particular situation. If you're running a web server for example, you probably want to run something like nginx and have it gracefully reload your program without interrupting clients.

@flakes My program is keep tracking some data from web, the html parse rule can be changed every day even every hour. So it is make sense to reload code of parsing html when the rule is changed.

Please have a read of __main__ — Top-level code environment and particularly the Idiomatic Usage sections. Then you will understand why Python is executing print("main1") twice here: once from the import main at the top and again from the importlib.reload(main).
To make a runner script run.py which live-reloads changes in main.py, you may want to look at the stdlib utility runpy. Then you can structure the two scripts like this:
main.py:
def fun():
    print("main2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("main1")
    fun()

run.py:
import time
import main
import runpy

while True:
    try:
        runpy.run_module("main", run_name="__main__")
    except Exception as err:
        print("error", err)
    time.sleep(1)

